# Split string to words after a given symbol in java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

My string would be like :

```
String s = "args: val args1: val1 args2: val3 /*...argsn: valn*/";
///*...argsn: valn*/ means that the string may contain n number of args and vals
```

Where:
 args os s word or a combination of words i already know
 val can be a single word or a full text that may contain words and symbols like ":" or ","...
What i want to do is display for any given 'args' display it's 'val'

Here's what i tried :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "arg1: val1 arg2: val2 arg3: va:l3";

        String[] rawPairs = s.replace(": ", ":").split(" ");

        Map<String, String> argsMap = Arrays.stream(rawPairs).collect(toMap(pair -> pair.substring(0, pair.indexOf(":")), pair -> pair.substring(pair.indexOf(":") + 1)));
        System.out.println(argsMap.get("arg3"));
        System.out.println(argsMap.get("arg5"));

    }
}
```

this works if the 'val' is a single word but once it's a text i get this error for this input :

```
String s = "arg1: val1 arg2: val2 is a sentence  arg3: va:l3";
```

Errors :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
at mainTest.lambda$main$0(mainTest.java:306)
at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1320)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at mainTest.main(mainTest.java:306)
```

Comment: you need another delimiter maybe... something that must not occur in the arg or val.

Comment: you would have to choose which format the string would have exactly. you gave 2 different examples

Comment: still not chosen completely... first string you show is `String s = "args: val args1: val1 args2: val3 /*...argsn: valn*/";` then you show `String s = "arg1: val1 arg2: val2 arg3: va:l3";` and as last you show `String s = "arg1 : val1 arg2 : val2 is a sentence  arg3 : va:l3";`. these are 3 completely different cases. chose 1 and we could work something out

Comment: maybe split on `arg\\d:` to get a list of values. If you need to parse the number inside the argument, use a regex.

Comment: The only thing i didn't pay attention to is that every args should be directly be followed by a ":" with no space but for the "va:l3" /"val2 is a sentence" is a way to say the value of a "val" may be a sentence or contain symbols

Comment: okay, now we are down to 2 possible strings: `String s1 = "args: val args1: val1 args2: val3 /*...argsn: valn*/";` and `String s2 = "arg1: val1 arg2: val2 arg3: va:l3";`. now chose which you want... `s1` or `s2`???

Comment: I think you didn't follow what i said a val can contain words and symbols as well, i think in this case the two possible strings you said are the same for me. Thank you

Comment: they are completely not the same, because one has one `arg` while the other has `args` which does make the difference between a working and a not working solution

Comment: Omg it's a naming mistake  args is arg

Comment: I hope that with this great power of noticing your future answer would be the one that&#39;s going to solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: You said that `args os s word or a combination of words i already know` , so, can arg actually be anything or is it necessarily `argX` where `X` is a number ?

Comment: yes exactly it can be anything but i already know what it could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Pattern & Matcher like below:

```
String s = "arg1 : val1 arg2 : val2 arg3 : va:l3";

if (s.contains("arg")) {

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("arg1 :(.*?)arg2");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
  while (matcher.find()) {
       System.out.println(matcher.group(1));                                
       String value = matcher.group(1);
       System.out.println(value);   
  }
}
```

The above code gets you all the characters between `"arg1 :"` and `"arg2"`. Do as per your requirement.

Comment: Indeed it works for " args : val" not my case, check the edit please

Comment: Did not OP ask to parse any argN: val pairs? Not arg1 and arg2...why is this upvoted?

Comment: Its just a sample to get characters between two other characters in a String. It could be helpful if the above given code is looped as per requirement.

Comment: You would loop one regex multiple times?... For this code to properly work, you'd need to rewrite your regex, and that gets too complicated. In my experience it's best to avoid regex expressions in your code unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Try it with a regular expression:

```
String s = "arg1 : val1 arg2 : val2 is a sentence  arg3 : va:l3";
Map<String, String> argMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
Matcher argMatcher = Pattern.compile("arg\\d*\\s?:\\s.*?(?=(\\s+arg\\d|$))").matcher(s);

while (argMatcher.find())
{
    String match = argMatcher.group();
    String[] pair = match.split("\\s\\:\\s");
    argMap.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
}

System.out.println(argMap);
```

It prints:

```
{arg3=va:l3, arg2=val2 is a sentence, arg1=val1}
```

Comment: i think OP wants a map consisting of arg and its val

Comment: and sadly we still dont know on which string exactly he want to operate

Comment: Also, there is a `:` outputted on the third value which i don't think is what the OP wants

Comment: @DCON `val can be a single word or a full text that may contain words and symbols like ":" or ","...` it is  possible for the val to contain `:`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer my bad I skimmed over that part as him wanting to use that as delimiter, not that it can include

Comment: You are all right. I didn't understand he wanted the keys, too.

Comment: if you replace the string by: `"arg1 : val1 arg2 : val2 is a sentence  arg3 : va:l3arg4"`, you should get : `arg3 = va:l3arg4`, but your piece of code prints `arg3 = va:l3,`

Comment: Yeah, OK, fine :) so change the pattern to `arg\\d*\\s?:\\s.*?(?=(\\s+arg\\d|$))`

Answer (score 2):

The expression you are trying to parse is ambiguous.

For example, you can't differentiate `food: bread score: 10`, which according to your definition could mean either:

- `arg1:food`,  `val1:bread` and `arg2:score`,  `val2:10`
- `arg1:food`,  `val1:bread score: 10` (since `:` can be part of the value)

As long as there will be ambiguous cases such as this one, you won't be able to reliably split your string.

You need to find a better, more reliable represention of the data you want to parse.

For example, you can represent your data as a json string

```
 {"arg1":"val1","arg2":"val2",...}
```

Answer (score 1):

As we still don't know what exactly the string looks like, I'll give 2 pretty similar solutions:

```
String s = "arg1: val1 arg2: val2 arg3: va:l3";
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
String[] splitted = s.split("arg\\d*:");
for (int i = 1; i < splitted.length; i++) {
    map.put(String.valueOf("arg" + (i)), splitted[i].trim());
}
System.out.println(map);
```

for the case that the String contains `arg` and

```
    String s = "arg1: val1 arg2: val2 arg3: va:l3";
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    String[] splitted = s.split("args\\d*:");
    for (int i = 1; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        map.put(String.valueOf("arg" + (i)), splitted[i].trim());
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

for the case that the String contains `args`. This solution also fills the data in a map to access key and value separately

Answer (score 1):

A bit too late, but here is the code which really parses the original string into the following:

```
arg1: val1 
arg2: val2 
arg3: 
va:l3
```

just a bit elaborated

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    String argStr = "arg1: val1 arg2: val2 arg3: va:l3";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|\\s)(\\w+:)");
    Matcher m;
    LinkedList<StringBuilder>  argLst = new LinkedList<>();

    while ((m = p.matcher(argStr)).find()) {
        if (m.start(1) > 0) 
            argLst.getLast().append(argStr.substring(0, m.start(1)));
        if (!argLst.isEmpty())
            argLst.getLast().append(m.group(1));
        argLst.add(new StringBuilder(m.group(2)));
        argStr = argStr.substring(m.end(2));
    }
    if (!argStr.isEmpty() && !argLst.isEmpty())  
        argLst.getLast().append(argStr);


    for (StringBuilder sb: argLst) 
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```